# Protractor - JavaScript - Is there a way to only locate objects within certain part of code

Tags: javascript, protractor

Situation is as follows:
I have a big table on my page, when I click on any of the items pop up opens with new table in it. Since we use one component for all the tables, and just use it wherever we need table, we get the same naming of both tables.

```
    <table1>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
      </tr>
    </table1>

<pop-up>
    <table1>
      <tr>
        <td>Mike</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>George</td>
      </tr>
    </table1>
</pop-up>
```

So, when I try to locate any cell in table, with $$, I get count from both table from page and from pop-up. And since number of rows in table/s is going to change daily, this really hardens things up.

**Bonus situation**: What if I had more pop-ups with more tables?

Is there a way to "say" to Protractor to only look for locators in  part of the code? I do not need to look through table that is in background (original page).

Comment: Shouldn't the component be able to differentiate between multiple instances of itsself? Like with an id?

Comment: Is there always only one pop up no matter how many times you clicked on the original table?  or the amount of pop ups is same as the click times, and only one pop up at top at one time?

Comment: @ Shilly - In current implementation it does not, it is one component that we use over and over again.


@ yong - Only one pop up for now, but as I said in "Bonus", what should I do if I have multiple pop ups, with multiple "same" tables?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check this:
https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first
you can set the index you want, also works with 'get(2)', 'get(3)' and so on...
like this - element.all(by.id('table1')).get(2).then(function... //you will get the second id

Or use xpath to differentiate the elements using the index (same as get but with [])
to make it easier use the extension to chrome: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo?hl=en

Comment: I understand that, but that was not what I was asking about. 
In your example, how do you differentiate in which "table1" is this going to get(2)?

Comment: When you search for an element with an id (or any other attribute) that is duplicated, protractor will return you an array of the found elements, and by default, use always the first one, this order will be according to the order in the html. 
if you know that the element you want will always be the third for example, then you can set the get(3).
The 'chropath' I told you helps to add searches to avoid this array of objects and getting the one you need

Comment: I also understand that, but since (as I said) number of rows is going to change daily, I cannot  rely on it to be always the "third one". That's why I "need" to access that one part of the code, and get item from there.

I also saw 'chropath', it is useful indeed, thanks!